# Bias-Variance decomposition for non-squared loss

Tags: loss-functions, bias-variance-tradeoff

While the Bias-Variance decomposition of the squared loss is part of any introductory ML class, I am curious to know if similar decompositions can be done for other loss functions, e.g., cross entropy?

Comment: A near-duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192286/bias-variance-decomposition  See through the list https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bias+varian*+decompo*+answers%3A1

Comment: Do the following search in google scholar: "bias-variance tradeoff for general loss function" (without the quotes). Many very relevant hits

Answer (score 2):

These two papers might be relevant:

- Shivaswamy, et al, [Bias-Variance Decomposition for Ranking](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3437963.3441772), WSDM 2021
- Yang, et al, [Rethinking Bias-Variance Trade-off for Generalization of Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.11328.pdf), PMLR 2020

The latter states some result for binary cross entropy.