# Bias-Variance decomposition: Expectations over what?

Tags: expected-value, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

The Bias Variance decomposition is a decomposition of an **expectation**, but I fail to follow what's actually assumed **random** specifically in this decomposition.

Take the specific regression example below in **Eq. 7.9** from [ESL](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12.pdf).  Is this expectation:

1. across multiple **fits** of the model? (i.e. across multiple trainings?)
2. across different **data points** x?

I get the impression that it's case #1, but that would be odd. The data is the data that we have for fitting, so what type of fits would they be?

E.g. is this looking at the **generalization error**? that is, for **any** dataset that we train with (not necessarily the one that we have) what $\text{Err}(x_0)$ we would see for a given generic point $x_0$? Or something else?

[image]

Comment: Expectation is over all possible samples. It’s very confusing here, but they somewhat mention that somewhere else IIRC

Comment: Thanks @user765195 By all possible samples, what do you mean exactly? (samples of data points $x$? samples of datasets $X$?) The current answer I got says it's done to the prediction error on a **fixed observation**. Would you say that's not correct?

Comment: Look at the discussion in Ch. 2. Over there, notice that the expectations are wrt the distribution of $\Tau$, the training set.

Comment: The math in ESL is not very rigorous and I also had hard time to understand this paragraph. I found this post very helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164378/bias-variance-decomposition-and-independence-of-x-and-epsilon?rq=1, and also this course: https://work.caltech.edu/telecourse.

Answer (score 1):

The Bias-Variance Decomposition is done to the prediction error on a fixed observation in the test set.

We assume we resample our training set again and again and re-train the model with each of the resampled train sets.

For example, the estimation of the error goes in this way: After we get $N$ train sets by resampling, we fit $N$ models with each of $N$ train sets. With the each of fitted models, we make a prediction on the same observation(OOS) in the test set. With the predictions, we will have $N$ predicted values, and the expected value of errors is calculated by taking the average of all the prediction errors.

The bias-variance decomposition states that the estimated error consists of error from bias, error from variance, and reducible error.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. So what is are the expectations integrating over in the Equations I posted in my question? And why would it say $\text{Err}(x_0)$? (i.e. the expectations seem to be _conditional_ on $X=x_0$)?

Comment: @Josh It's conditional on $x_0$ because we want to test our model with the observation ($x_0$, $y_0$). So the error is calculated with the label $y_0$. The expectation is taken over the training sets.

Comment: You may check the Wikipedia article(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff). It explains more clearly.

Comment: Well if you fix the observation, it doesn't make sense to include the irreducible error. Remember $Y = f(X) + \epsilon$. If you fix the observation $(x_0, y_0)$ then $y_0 = f(x_0) + e_0$. Randomness is gone if you specify both $x_0$ and $y_0$.